# Class reference types (metaclasses) in dart?

Tags: dart

I'm new to this dart shenanigans and am having trouble migrating my mindset to its design philosophy. In particular, I am used to the Object Pascal way of being able to define types of types and class reference types and combining them with enums for use in class factories, for example:

```pascal
type
  Animal = (Cat, Dog, Bird); // enum

  TAnimal = abstract class;
  AnimalClass = class of TAnimal; // metaclass definition: a reference to the type of the class

  TCat = class(TAnimal)
   constructor Create(....);
  end

  TDog = class(TAnimal)
   constructor Create(....);
  end

  TBird = class(TAnimal)
   constructor Create(....);
  end

const AnimalClassRef = array[Animals] of AnimalClass = (TCat, TDog [, ..etc..]);

function CreateAnimal(const aAnimal : Animal): TAnimal;
begin
  // the enum maps to the metaclass, the appropriate constructor is called
  // and an instance is returned
  result := AnimalClassRef[aAnimal].Create;
end;

// usage:
CreateAnimal(Cat); // meow
CreateAnimal(Dog); // woof
```

This pattern should be very familiar to coders steeped in its lore. Apart from the extreme type safety, one of the big advantages is that the ordinal value of the enum (i.e Cat=0, Dog=1) can be stored/transmitted easily and used directly to make the factory flexible at runtime:

```
const SomeAnimal : integer = 2; // or read this from a file or get it from a listview index etc 
CreateAnimal(TAnimal(SomeAnimal)); // chirp
```

My question is a combination of hows: how does this pattern translate to the dart way? How would I accomplish something similar in dart and what, if any, sugar is there to be sprinkled? Can I translate the array of references to a dart Map somehow?

Thanks!

**UPDATE:** The type keyword gives me the type reflection I need, but I could simply use a map, like so:

```dart
enum Animal { cat, dog }

abstract class Critter {
  void speak();
}
  
class Cat extends Critter {
  @override
  void speak() {
    print('meow');
  }
}

class Dog extends Critter {
  @override
  void speak() {
    print('woof');
  }
}

Map<Animal, dynamic> critterMap = {
 Animal.cat: () => Cat(),
 Animal.dog: () => Dog()
};

.
.
.

Critter critter1 = critterMap[Animal.cat]();
Critter critter2 = critterMap[Animal.dog]();
critter1.speak(); // meow
critter2.speak(); // woof
```

Since Map keys can be strings, I can do away with the enum. The enum is superfluous really because dart doesn't seem to support compiletime-enforced enum-bounded lists (or maps for that matter). As a result, it seems glaringly error-prone to me but it *does* allow me to do what I want, which is to generate an instance given some other metadata.

Comment: In Dart, types for constructors and static methods must all be resolved at compile time. You can't have a variable that "holds a type" and do anything much more than query it to dispatch code manually.  Even generics are all resolved at compile time.

Comment: @RandalSchwartz Randal, thanks for the response. I've cobbled together a workaround. It's not perfect but neither is dart.

Answer (score 0):

One thing to keep in mind with dart enums is that it autogenerates a static `.values` method which stores an array of all its members, and each member also has an autogenerated `.index` method which stores its position in the values array.

```dart
enum Animal {cat, dog, bird}
void main() {
  print(Animal.values); // [Animal.cat, Animal.dog, Animal.bird]
  print(Animal.cat.index); // 0
  print(Animal.dog.index); // 1
  print(Animal.bird.index); // 2
  print(Animal.values[Animal.bird.index]); // Animal.bird
}
```

The above should allow you to serialize and deserialize from an integer value.

But how to then translate the `Animal` to the `Critter`? I can think of three different approaches.

The first approach would be to create a [factory constructor](https://dart.dev/language/constructors#factory-constructors) within the `Critter` class.

```dart
sealed class Critter {
  void speak();
  
  Critter();
  
  factory Critter.createAnimal(Animal animal) {
    return switch (animal) {
       Animal.cat => Cat(),
       Animal.dog => Dog(),
       Animal.bird => Bird(),
    };
  }
}

...

void main() {
  const int someAnimal = 2;
  Critter critter = Critter.createAnimal(Animal.values[someAnimal]);
  critter.speak(); // chirp
}
```

Some things to note about the above solution is that [switch expressions](https://dart.dev/language/branches#switch-expressions) are [exhaustive](https://dart.dev/language/branches#exhaustiveness-checking) over enums which is less error prone than doing a map lookup. Additionally, I recommend using [sealed](https://dart.dev/language/class-modifiers#sealed) over [abstract](https://dart.dev/language/class-modifiers#abstract) since it has exhaustiveness checking as well, the only requirement is that all subclasses of sealed are defined in the same file.

The second approach would be to make `createAnimal` a method on the `Animal` enum instead of adding a factory constructor to `Critter`.

```dart
enum Animal {
  cat,
  dog,
  bird;

  Critter createAnimal() {
    return switch (this) {
      cat => Cat(),
      dog => Dog(),
      bird => Bird(),
    };
  }
}

...

void main() {
  const int someAnimal = 2;
  Critter critter = Animal.values[someAnimal].createAnimal();
  critter.speak(); // chirp
}
```

One thing to note here is that inside the enum you are allowed to refer to its members as say `cat` instead of `Animal.cat`.

The third approach would be to simply use a standalone function.

```dart
Critter createAnimal(Animal animal) {
  return switch (animal) {
    Animal.cat => Cat(),
    Animal.dog => Dog(),
    Animal.bird => Bird(),
  };
}

...

void main() {
  const int someAnimal = 2;
  Critter critter = createAnimal(Animal.values[someAnimal]);
  critter.speak(); // chirp
}
```

It's mostly just a matter of preference as to which approach/syntax you prefer.